# Composer auto-load fails inside post-install script

Tags: php, composer-php, package-managers

Seems like composer can't load psr-4 class when running post-install command.

Here is my composer.json:

```
{
  "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
        "Modules\\": "modules/",
        "ComposerScript\\": ""
      }
  },
 "scripts": {
    "post-install-cmd": [
      "ComposerScript\\ComposerScript::postInstall"
    ]
  }
}
```

`ComposerScript.php` contains:

```
<?php

namespace ComposerScript;

use Modules\Common\Services\RouterService;
use Composer\Script\Event as ComposerEvent;

class ComposerScript
{

    public static function postInstall(ComposerEvent $event)
    {

        $vendorDir = $event->getComposer()->getConfig()->get('vendor-dir');

        require $vendorDir . '/autoload.php';

        echo 'class exist: ';
        var_dump(class_exists('Modules\Common\Services\RouterService'));

        $router = new \Modules\Common\Services\RouterService();
    }
}
```

After running `composer install`
Output:

> Generating autoload files ComposerScript\ComposerScript::postInstall
>
> class exist: bool(false)
>
> PHP Fatal error:  Class
> 'Modules\Common\Services\RouterService' not found in /var/www/project/ComposerScript.php on line 19

When running project from apache autoloader works properly.
Also locally it works.
Probably some server configuration, but which one....

Any help or reference appreciated.

Comment: Does the file `modules\Common\Services\RouterService.php` exist? Beware case sensitivity!

Comment: @Sven, yes it exist. Also it's fun I can't debug anything because composer override ClassLoader.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue was with **PSR-4** autoloading:

http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/

Folders should be with first letter upper case like class name:

```
{
  "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
        "Modules\\": "Modules/",
        "ComposerScript\\": ""
      }
  }
}


$router = new \Modules\Common\Services\RouterService();
```

Should match:

```
-Modules
 -Common
  -Services
   -RouterService.php
```